# Stitch surfaces into Solid3D

Tags: eyeshot

Is it possible to stitch together surfaces into a Solid3D using Eyeshot?
Or must we detect coincident edges and stitch together our self by creating the Solid3D and adding edges, vertices & faces?

Comment: That is very difficult to do. I did do it similar but i knew the generic shape it had so what i did is it created a `Region` for each surface and extruded them toward the center into a `Solid3D` and then merge all solids one by one. This created an hollow shape inside and i didn't care about that drawback. You can if you need fill it up with an extra step. If you prefer knitting you should send a ticket to the support but if i recall it's either not accessible to us the users or very very complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can do a variation of this using `Solid`.  There is a way to do boolean operations, like Adding or Subtracting volumes of two Solids.
These functions can be used as

```
Solid[] differences = Solid.Difference(solidA, solidB);
Solid[] unions = Solid.Union(solidA, solidB);`
```

Hopefully this helps.  You can also use this with mesh by converting the mesh to a solid, then do the operations as a solid.  Then convert the list of solids back to meshes.